# Pushing an OR into the node check

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

To do an `OR` on two different nodes, I can do the following:

```
//C:Year[not(@value="2019")] | //R:Year[not(@value="2019")]
```

However, if there is a long expression, this becomes a bit unwieldy, especially if there are more than 2 ORs. Is there a way to do something like the following:

```
//(C:Year or R:Year)[not(@value="2019")]
```

Basically, is it possible rather than evaluate the full `axis-node-predicate` expression and OR-ing the full thing, to be able to put an `OR` within the node test itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (only) works in XPath 2.0+

```
//(C:Year | R:Year)[not(@value="2019")]
```

But, unfortunately, not in XPath 1.0.

The W3C [XPath 1.0 language reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) states under 3.1:

> Parentheses may be used for grouping.
>
> ```
> [14] Expr        ::= OrExpr   
> [15] PrimaryExpr ::= VariableReference | '(' Expr ')' | Literal | Number | FunctionCall
> ```

However `/steps/` (*`StepExpr`) are not mentioned.

But the XPath 2.0 ref states:

> Parentheses must be used when "`/`" is used on the left hand side of
> an operator, as in "`(/) * 5`".

With this hint I came up with this query that also works in XPath 1.0:

```
((//C:Year)|(//C:Year))[not(@value="2019")]
```

So, v2+ is more flexible but the same principle applies. Gustafson, M. Kay, and others discussed an XPath 2.0 [bug](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=4868) long this lines leading to [Errata XP.E3](https://www.w3.org/XML/2007/qt-errata/xpath20-errata.html#E3). D. Chamberlin:

> On July 31, 2007, the Query and XSLT working groups agreed to add
> parentheses to the expansions of leading-/ and leading-// in path
> expressions, as suggested by this bug report. The revised expansions
> will appear in a future errata document. Regards, Don Chamberlin (for
> the joint working groups)

Comment: @wp -- I see, thanks for this. I've been having trouble locating a good source on where parentheticals are acceptable in XPath 1 -- what are the general rules of where it can be used (or does it say so anywhere in the w3c doc?).

Comment: Let me check; When I run this in Java with XPath 1.0: `ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.`